# Is the function math.ulp more precise than the explicit formula in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, numerical-analysis

In floating-point arithmetic, the [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) (ULP) of a floating-point number is the spacing between that number and the consecutive one, i.e. the value of its least significant digit (rightmost digit) if it is 1. It is given by this formula:

> ULP(*x*) = *b*<sup>−(*p*−1)</sup> • |*x*|

where *b* is the base (2 for binary numerals) and *p* (53 for double-precision significands) is the precision.

Python 3.9 introduced a new function [`math.ulp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ulp) to compute the ULP of a floating-point number.

With this function, the previous formula is verified as expected for the ULP of 1:

```py
>>> math.ulp(1)
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> 2**(-(53 - 1)) * abs(1)
2.220446049250313e-16
```

but it is not verified for the ULP of 10<sup>−10</sup> for instance:

```py
>>> math.ulp(1e-10)
1.2924697071141057e-26
>>> 2**(-(53 - 1)) * abs(1e-10)
2.2204460492503132e-26
```

Is `math.ulp(x)` more precise than `2**(-(53 - 1)) * abs(x)`? Why?

The CPython implementation is in [Modules/mathmodule.c#L3408-L3427](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Modules/mathmodule.c#L3408-L3427) but I cannot find the implementation of the called function `nextafter` to understand:

```c
static double
math_ulp_impl(PyObject *module, double x)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=f5207867a9384dd4 input=31f9bfbbe373fcaa]*/
{
    if (Py_IS_NAN(x)) {
        return x;
    }
    x = fabs(x);
    if (Py_IS_INFINITY(x)) {
        return x;
    }
    double inf = m_inf();
    double x2 = nextafter(x, inf);
    if (Py_IS_INFINITY(x2)) {
        /* special case: x is the largest positive representable float */
        x2 = nextafter(x, -inf);
        return x - x2;
    }
    return x2 - x;
}
```

Comment: nextafter is a function in the C standard library. I'd expect the built-in ulp to be more reliable, simply because it is... well, simpler, and sticks to subtraction, whereas the explicit formula does some fancy math (exponentiation) right at the edges of the capabilities of the very thing it is trying to investigate. But I haven't analyzed it in detail, so this is a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: FYI, “the spacing between that number and the consecutive one” is not a correct description of ULP. The spacing from −2 to the next representable number, −1.9999something, is half the ULP of −2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, you are absolutely right, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place#Definition), ULP(*x*) = 2^(-(53 - 1)) * 2^exponent(*x*) where exponent(*x*) is the IEEE 754 [normalized exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Example) of *x*, i.e. `math.ulp(x) == 2**(-(53 - 1)) * 2**math.floor(math.log2(x))`. Could you write an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2<sup>−(53−1)</sup> • |*x*| (or `2**(-(53 - 1)) * abs(x)`) is not a formula for ULP(*x*) (or `math.ulp(x)`) because it does not give the value of a 1 in the position of the lowest bit of *x* but rather the value of the significand of *x* (1.something) scaled to the position of the lowest bit of *x*. When *x* is not a power of two, its significand exceeds 1, and the formula is too high.

The [correct formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place#Definition) is 2<sup>−(53−1)</sup> • 2<sup>max(*e*, −1022)</sup> where *e* is the IEEE 754 [normalized exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Example) of *x*, i.e. 2<sup>*e*</sup> ≤ |*x*| < 2<sup>*e*+1</sup> (or `2**(-(53 - 1)) * 2**max(math.floor(math.log2(x)), -1022)`).